# The intersection of infinite open set is closed : Because of the countability of $\mathbb N$?

Tags: general-topology

Question copied from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339898/why-can-the-intersection-of-infinite-open-sets-be-closed).

> In $E^2$, let $X$ be the infinite family of concentric open disks of radius $1 + 1/n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$. Why is $X$ a closed set?

The question in a nutshell , why :
$$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(-1-\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=[-1,1]$$?

This question was clearly solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339898/why-can-the-intersection-of-infinite-open-sets-be-closed), **but** I have heard the argument that *it is a countable intersection* (because $n\in\mathbb N$) so then $n$ will never reach $+\infty$. I have a doubt about it.

Someone may confirm or disprove with an argument ?

Comment: *Infinite* intersection is enough.

Comment: Countability is not the relevant issue. It's the same if you replace $\mathbb N$ with $\mathbb R^+$ which clearly is uncountable. However note that the set $\{-1-1/n|n\in\mathbb N\}$ has no maximum, nor has $\{-1-1/n|n\in\mathbb R^+\}$. Note that *finite* intersections of open sets are always open, so the fact that there are infinitely many sets is important. Also note that finite sets of real numbers always have a maximum and a minimum.

Comment: Consider the analogous situation in 1 dimension: $[-1,1]=\cap_{n\in \mathbb N}(-1-1/n,1+1/n)=\cap_{r>0}(-1-r,1+r).$

Answer (score 2):

$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(-1-\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\supseteq[-1,1]$ is clear, so we only have to prove the other containment:

$$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(-1-\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\subseteq[-1,1]$$

Let $x\in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(-1-\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

This means that $-1-\frac{1}{n}<x<1+\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$.

Taking limits as $n\to\infty$, we get $-1\leq x\leq 1$, i.e. $x\in [-1,1]$.

We have proved the other containment.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\bigcap_{x\in \mathbb R}(1-\frac{1}{1+x^2},1+\frac{1}{1+x^2})=\{1\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Infinity is not a number. $n$ will never reach $+\infty$ in the sense that $+\infty\notin\mathbb{N}$. But there are arbitrarily large $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$, that could be written as $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} n=+\infty$. You can also interprete this as "there is no number greater than all natural numbers".

$\mathbb{N}$ being countable (countably infinite) is not necessary for the intersection to be closed.
$$\bigcap_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}}\left(-1-\frac{1}{x}, 1+\frac{1}{x}\right) = [-1,1]$$
is true as well.

The important points are that

1. For $y>1$ you can always find an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $1+\frac{1}{n}<y$.
2. There is no $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $1+\frac{1}{n} \leq 1$.